# faceing issue in webview flutter showing blank screen in 3.0.0 version

Tags: android, ios, flutter

facing issue in review flutter showing the blank screen in 3.0.0 version
and it's in ios   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NUSk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Android, with versions 3.0.0 and 2.4.0. So I tested downgrading back to 2.3.1, which is what we were using before, and explicitely selecting the hybrid composition mode, by adding:

```
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
```

in initState, as described in https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/versions/2.3.1

*The issue also occurs*. So it's probably not specific to v3.0.0.

Another interesting observation: the issue remains present if we upgrade to 3.0.0, then downgrade back to 2.3.1 (removing the aforementioned code which explicitly activates hybrid composition), and cleanup the pub caches...

So it might be caused by a third-party dependency but I don't understand why cleaning up the dep cache doesn't fix the issue when reverting back from 3.0.0 to 2.3.1...